# Изменение очерёдности выполнения асинхронных задач AsynkTask.

Tags: android, java, android-asynctask

**Дано**:

Есть ViewPager, содержащий фрагменты. Они стартуют чрез запрос к сервису AsynkTask-и, лезущие в эти ваши интернеты. При быстром пролистывании фрагментов запускается множество задач, становящихся в очередь.

**Задача**:

Надо бы как-то изменить порядок (приоритет) выполнения этих задач. Иначе задача, запущенная текущим фрагментом выполняется последней, что раздражает.

**Вопрос**:

Собственно вопрос в том, как получить список выполняющихся задач и поменять их очерёдность. Беглое гугленье не помогло (видать не те параметры гуглу передаю).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> и поменять их очерёдность

Это не совсем правильный вариант. Правильнее будет отменять задачи для фрагментов, находящихся вне экрана. Для этого нужно правильно составить doInBackground() метод, чтобы можно было прервать выполнение. Например, использовать какой-то флаг, который периодически проверять, и как только он примет определенное значение, прервать выполнение таски. Так же создать, например, очередь из AsyncTask, в которой может содержаться максимум 3 (например) таски, и как только добавляется четвертая - отменять выполнение первой.

Еще один (не очень правильный) вариант - переопределить политику ThreadPoolExecutor так, чтобы он одновременно выполнял несколько тасок. Подробнее писать не буду, уже ничего не соображаю. По этому вопросу нагуглить довольно просто.

Comment: @metalurgus, ОК, это, положим, подойдёт в случае быстрого пролистывания множества фрагментов. Но у меня есть случай, когда одновременно запускаются обязательные 4-е задачи (1-ый ViewPager запускает 2шт, в данный момент не приоритетные, но нужные; при этом он стартует ещё один ViewPager, коий запускает ещё 2шт) В итоге отображаемый фрагмент оказывается 3-им в очереди из 4 задач. И все 4-е нужны. Про параллельное исполнение доки почитал - не рекомендуют, да. Засим вопрос о ручной смене очерёдности запущенных задач остаётся открытым.

Comment: если задачи исполняются последвательно, то чтобы изменить очередность, нужно дождаться выполнения одной из них или прервать текущую. Можно сделать просто список задач на выполнение, а AsyncTask просто при старте проверяет, есть ли в этом списке задача и выполняет ее. По окончанию задачи он перезапускает себя. Так как очередь (то есть массив/список) задач в Вашем полном распоряжении, то можно будет перемещать задачи в произвольном порядке.

Также, видимо, придется обучить задачу прерываться в произвольном месте. Но это уже немного сложнее будет.

Comment: Т.е. нема стандартных методов типа **List<AsynkTask>  getListOfExecutingTasks()** и **setMaxPriority(AsynkTask task)**?

Comment: OK, видать таки придётся всё это в List складывать и проверять на конкретные случаи по ссылкам.